# Plotly: refresh data passed to px.line via dropdown from Database

Tags: python, plotly, dashboard, reload, interactive

I want to use the plotly express lineplot to create a simple interactive plot that refreshes its data when choosing a new item in a dropdown box.

I have created a simple function `prepare_dashboard_data` which loads data from a database and does some filtering. The dashboard is showing the data from the initial dataload but I am completely lost on how to create a callback to the `px.line` function, such that the plot is updated with new data loaded from the database.

I have taken inspiration from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61461583/plotly-dropdown-selection-does-not-update-plots-correctly/61463810#61463810) where `plotly.graph_objs` are used. But i quite like the functionality of the default lineplot.
And in the example a preloaded dataframe is simply filtered based on the dropdown choice. This is not what I want.

I have some limited knowledge with ipython widgets and the observer pattern, but I am completely lost in this case. Here is a rough sceme of my current code:

```
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import plotly.express as px


def prepare_dashboard_data(serverconfig, shopname = "myshop"):
    # Data is loaded form a db 
    # Transformed filtered by shopname and so on ...
    # This returns a datframe with has an timestamp as an index and many items as columns

    return df
    
# Prepare Dropdown menues
shopnames = df.columns # This just gives a list of available shopnames.

# plotly start 
fig = go.Figure()

fig = px.line(prepare_dashboard_data(serverconfig=conf, shopname = "myshop"),width=1600, height=800)
# menu setup    
updatemenu= []

# buttons for menu 1, shopnames
buttons=[]

# should i create traces for each shopnames alread here: 
for webshop_name in shopnames :
    buttons.append(dict(method='update',
                        label=webshop_name,
                        visible=True,
                        args=[#{I guess here goes the magic?}
                                ]
                        )
                )

# some adjustments to the updatemenus
updatemenu=[]
your_menu=dict()
updatemenu.append(your_menu)
updatemenu[0]['buttons']=buttons
updatemenu[0]['direction']='down'
updatemenu[0]['showactive']=True

fig.update_layout(
    autosize=False,
    width=1800,
    height=800,
    margin=dict(
        l=50,
        r=50,
        b=100,
        t=100,
        pad=4
    ),
    updatemenus=updatemenu,
    paper_bgcolor="LightSteelBlue",
)

fig.show()
```

Any help would be really appreciated. I have tried to make sense of the documentation but i think i would need a pointer. Currently i generate my plots in a Vscode/jupyter notebook, not as a standalone app .

Answer (score 0):

You should use plotly-Dash to solve this. Here is an example you can tune to fit the structure of your dataframe.

```
from dash import Dash, dcc, html, Input, Output
import pandas as pd
import plotly.express as px

app = Dash(__name__)

app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(['a','b','c'], 'a', id='dropdown'),
    dcc.Graph(id='graph')
    ])



df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'a': [1,2,3,4,5],
         'b': [-1,-2,-3,-4,-5],
         'c': [2,4,6,8,10]
        }
       )


@app.callback(
        Output(component_id='graph', component_property='figure'),
        Input(component_id='dropdown', component_property='value')
       )
def update_output(column):
    fig = px.line(df, x=column)
    return fig

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: i would prefer to run my plots in an notebook. I have solved my Problem by using graph objects and scatter. Is dash also able to run in a notebook?